# Cohort analysis by weeknumber on two tables to check user activation

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a cohort analysis by weeknumber that tells me how many people(devices) whose first session lasted at least 4 minutes.

Thank you,
Fred

Table sessions

```
id              varchar(20)  xevKchmQeZNUhp68thby       
_dev_UUID       varchar(20)  238516bf921ec379
start           datetime     2016-11-16 01:22:39            
stop            datetime     2016-11-16 01:23:06
```

Note: _dev_UUID is a proxy for user

With this query, I get all sessions > 4 min, but I want only the first session. I found MIN(start) may help, but were to put it for valid syntax?

SELECT WEEK(start) as WeekNumber, COUNT(*) AS Sessions,  SUM(TIMEDIFF(`stop`,`start`) > '00:04:00') AS ActivatedSessions FROM sessions WHERE `start` >=NOW()- INTERVAL 365 DAY GROUP BY WeekNumber ORDER BY `WeekNumber` ASC

Desired output:

A = #UsersWithFirstSessions>4min

B = %UsersWithFirstSessions>4min / UsersWithFirstSessions<4min

```
WeekNumber Week 44  Week 45 Week 46
A          66       53      49
B          23%      21%     18%
```

Comment: At a minimum, sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: I gave more info, hope it is clearer what I am after. Thank you.

Comment: Sessions per user can be calculated by `COUNT(*)` and grouping by user/device.